# Swift - MFMessageComposeViewController freezes when recipients are over 100

Tags: ios, swift

I want to send SMS message via ios (swift) application. I have a action on button like;

```
IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = messageTextView.text
            controller.recipients = selectedNumbers
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

"selectedNumbers" is an **Array of String** which contains the phone numbers of recipients.

When the array has;

- 1-50 numbers there is a ~3 sec delay while presenting
  MFMessageComposeViewController
- 50-200 numbers there is a ~5 - ~15 sec delay while presenting
  MFMessageComposeViewController

.
.

- Finally i try 800 numbers but app is freezing and not responding over
  4 minutes. If i m wait with patience sometimes
  MFMessageComposeViewController presenting sometimes not.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: But... but... I do have a question. Why would you do that? 50+ recipients? Isn't that spamming?

Comment: spam for what? You mean "for cellular service provider"? If it is..The answer is: in my country No :)

Comment: Hmm interesting. There's no spam thing I believe in SMS. One thing to check if there's really something up with that `MFMessageComposeViewController` is try to do the same thing with the native Messages app of iOS, and see if they will have the same behavior (lagging issue when recipients count > 50). If there's no issue, perhaps report it to Apple? :/